# Using regex in contains() to select rows from a pandas data frame having some string value (Capital or small)

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I want to extract rows from a pandas data frame based on the values of a column using regex in contains() method.

I am using the following code line to extract rows from a data frame if the 'COMPTYPE' column has any string value mentioned in contains() method

```
df = df[df['COMPTYPE'].astype(str).str.contains('MCCB|ACB|VCB|CONTACTOR', regex=True)]
```

It works fine however it's not selecting those rows which have MccB or Vcb or Contactor or acb etc. values in the 'COMPTYPE' column.
How to use this command so it will take rows irrespective of the case of the string values.

Input:

| BOARDIBNO | SUBCOMP_IBNO | COMPTYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1044444001 | 9044444001 | ACB |
| 1044444001 | 9044444002 | Relay |
| 1044444001 | 9044444003 | Meters |
| 1044444001 | 9044444004 | MCCB/MPCB |
| 1044444001 | 9044444005 | vcb |
| 1044444001 | 9044444006 | MCCB/MPCB |
| 1044444001 | 9044444007 | acb |
| 1044444001 | 9044444008 | mccb |
| 1044444001 | 9044444009 | MCCB/MPCB |
| 1044444001 | 9044444010 | Power Contactor |
| 1044444001 | 9044444011 | Power Contactor |
| 1044444001 | 9044444012 | Control Contactor |
| 1044444001 | 9044444013 | VCB |

Expected output is this,

| BOARDIBNO | SUBCOMP_IBNO | COMPTYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1044444001 | 9044444001 | ACB |
| 1044444001 | 9044444004 | MCCB/MPCB |
| 1044444001 | 9044444005 | vcb |
| 1044444001 | 9044444006 | MCCB/MPCB |
| 1044444001 | 9044444007 | acb |
| 1044444001 | 9044444008 | mccb |
| 1044444001 | 9044444009 | MCCB/MPCB |
| 1044444001 | 9044444010 | Power Contactor |
| 1044444001 | 9044444011 | Power Contactor |
| 1044444001 | 9044444012 | Control Contactor |
| 1044444001 | 9044444013 | VCB |

However, I'm getting following output,

| BOARDIBNO | SUBCOMP_IBNO | COMPTYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1044444001 | 9044444001 | ACB |
| 1044444001 | 9044444004 | MCCB/MPCB |
| 1044444001 | 9044444005 | MCCB/MPCB |
| 1044444001 | 9044444006 | MCCB/MPCB |
| 1044444001 | 9044444010 | VCB |

How to do it? Please help!

Comment: Why are you using ```regex``` for that?

Comment: It was giving me desired result to do further calculations. Please suggest if there is a better way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your expression is not case *in*sensitive, for example `MCCB` would match `MCCB` but not `MccB` or `mccb`

Comment: ```df[df['COMPTYPE'].str.contains('MCCB|ACB|VCB|CONTACTOR', case=False) == True]```

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine How to make it case sensitive?

Comment: Try passing case as `False` in [contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) eg: `df['column'].str.contains("word", case=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `flags=re.IGNORECASE` as parameter of `str.contains` or use `case=False` as suggested by @JoanLara:

```
import re
out = (df[df['COMPTYPE'].astype(str)
          .str.contains('MCCB|ACB|VCB|CONTACTOR', regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)]

print(out)

# Output
     BOARDIBNO  SUBCOMP_IBNO           COMPTYPE
0   1044444001    9044444001                ACB
3   1044444001    9044444004          MCCB/MPCB
4   1044444001    9044444005                vcb
5   1044444001    9044444006          MCCB/MPCB
6   1044444001    9044444007                acb
7   1044444001    9044444008               mccb
8   1044444001    9044444009          MCCB/MPCB
9   1044444001    9044444010    Power Contactor
10  1044444001    9044444011    Power Contactor
11  1044444001    9044444012  Control Contactor
12  1044444001    9044444013                VCB
```

Or upper case the column before:

```
>>> out = df[df['COMPTYPE'].astype(str).str.upper()
             .str.contains('MCCB|ACB|VCB|CONTACTOR', regex=True)]

print(out)

# Output
     BOARDIBNO  SUBCOMP_IBNO           COMPTYPE
0   1044444001    9044444001                ACB
3   1044444001    9044444004          MCCB/MPCB
4   1044444001    9044444005                vcb
5   1044444001    9044444006          MCCB/MPCB
6   1044444001    9044444007                acb
7   1044444001    9044444008               mccb
8   1044444001    9044444009          MCCB/MPCB
9   1044444001    9044444010    Power Contactor
10  1044444001    9044444011    Power Contactor
11  1044444001    9044444012  Control Contactor
12  1044444001    9044444013                VCB
```

Comment: @ShraddhaJadhav. Note you don't have to specify `regex=True` because this is the default option but `case=False` is mandatory for your problem.